# Objective-C runtime get NSArray<NSString *> *demo;

Tags: objective-c, runtime

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSArray<NSString *> *Data;//excemple
```

I use:

```
objc_property_t *propers = class_copyPropertyList(c, &count);
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    objc_property_t p = propers[i];
    NSLog(@"%s\n%s\n",property_getName(p),property_getAttributes(p));
}
```

The result is:

```
2016-05-01 20:04:10.952 demo-for-kvc-json[31505:538138] Data
T@"NSArray",C,N,V_Data
```

Who can tell me how to get the content of <>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Generics in Objective-C serve as a hint to the compiler only, that information is not encoded in the runtime.